# "Percentage of ... Higher than that [of/in] ..."

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context, grammatical-number

Which one is correct (using `of` or `in`):

> The percentage of tiny devices in the IPs dataset is higher than that
>   of the top websites.

Or

> The percentage of tiny devices in the IPs dataset is higher than that
>   in the top websites.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Starting with

> The percentage of tiny devices in the IPs dataset is higher than that of the top websites.

If you add one word

> The percentage of tiny devices **reported** in the IPs dataset is higher than that of the top websites.

and follow it through

> The percentage of tiny devices **reported** in the IPs dataset is higher than that **reported** of the top websites.

It becomes clear that "of" is wrong, so using the same preposition:

> The percentage of tiny devices **in** the IPs dataset is higher than that **in** the top websites.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct but have different meanings. "of" implies that the dataset was from the top websites themselves. "in" implies that the dataset is part of the top websites. a good example of the difference here would be

> They are of Canada

They were born in Canada, but it is implied that they are no longer in Canada

> They are in Canada

They are currently within Canada, but it is not implied that they were born in Canada